# Why is my parametrization for this curve incorrect for this line integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, parametric, parametrization, line-integrals

I'm trying to solve this line integral on Paul's notes: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Solutions/CalcIII/LineIntegralsPtI/Prob2.aspx, but I don't know why my parametrization isn't working. For the curve I'm using the equation $(3cos(t), 3sin(t))$ from $π<t<2π$ and setting up the integral $3\int_{2\pi}^{\pi}54cos^2(t)sin(t)-12cos(t)dt$ since it asked for the surface to be clockwise, but I'm still getting the negative of the answer Paul's notes gives.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> The integral is a _scalar_ line integral, whose value is independent of the direction of parametrization. Does that help?

Comment: In line integral of scalar field, we don't care the direction of the parametrization. The indication of the author " with clockwise rotation" is not relevant.